# Use Jsch from multiple thread, the result of some commands is always incomplete

Tags: java, multithreading, jsch

Every thread has a session but I found if Thread more than one ,the output of a specific command is incomplete。

I have 20 command need to get export, but i found has 3 command output always one row.

but these command in one thread is normal.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> cfs = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<Void>>();
AppConfig.nimblesMap.forEach((k, v)->{
    CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        System.out.println("Schedule start，Machine Name："+k+"; Date Time："+ sd.format(new Date()));
        String machineName = v.getMachineName();
        Session session = new JSch().getSession(v.getUserName(), null);
        session.setPassword(v.getPassWord());
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect(); 
        
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        channelExec.setCommand("command");
        channelExec.setInputStream(null);
        channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
        channelExec.getErrStream();
        channelExec.connect();
        InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String lineData;
        
        while((lineData = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineData = lineData.replaceAll("\\s+", ",");
        }
        
        in.close();
        channelExec.disconnect();
                
        session.disconnect();
    },executor);
    cfs.add(CompletableFuture.allOf(cf));
});
cfs.stream().forEach(v-> v.join() );
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Does your program hang?  Do you need to close the `channelExec.getOutputStream()`?  Maybe the jsch connections are waiting for use input that is never coming?

Comment: NO, it's running.
Only three command will cause this problem